# Tkinter and pillow operations

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I need some help,

Following is the code to display sliders in Tkinter,

```
from Tkinter import *

def show_values():
    print (w1.get(), w2.get())

master = Tk()
w1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=42)
w1.pack()
w2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
w2.pack()
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_values).pack()

mainloop()
```

Following is the filter code

```
from PIL import ImageFilter
im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(3))
```

I want to display the image filtering dynamically such that the argument passed to MinFilter() should change when we scroll the slider and image gets update. Can anyone please help?

Comment: `Scale( ... , command=show_values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scale` has `command=` which executes function with current value from scale

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter


def show_value_1(value):
    print('v1:', value)

    # filter image
    img = image.filter(ImageFilter.MinFilter(int(value)))

    # create new photo
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    # update image in label
    l['image'] = photo

    # PhotoImage has to be assigned to global variable - problem with "garbage collector"
    l.photo = photo


def show_value_2(value):
    print('v2:', value)


master = tk.Tk()

image = Image.open("ball-1.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

l = tk.Label(master, image=photo)
l.pack()
l.photo = photo

w1 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=42, command=show_value_1)
w1.pack()

w2 = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=show_value_2)
w2.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

ball-1.png

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton. I see that in l = tk.Label() and l.photo = photo is extra copy for garbage reference. Is that correct? I found http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm I will try the code tonight.

Comment: yes, I do it because of problem with garbage collector as described in link to effbot.org.